# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform Flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having troubles with the error in the question title, followed the official flutter tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqJ_KjFzL9I

Solved all errors that the IDE marked, and now my code has no errors but only get this message when I run the app.
my firestore db:
[image: firestore db]

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
class Cloudtest extends StatefulWidget {
  const Cloudtest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CloudtestState createState() => _CloudtestState();
}

class _CloudtestState extends State<Cloudtest> {
  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context,DocumentSnapshot document){
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(document['name'])
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todo').snapshots(),
        builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index) =>
            _buildListItem(context,snapshot.data!.docs[index]),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I expected to get was a list with the elements in the database, I call this page with a button in another flutter page, the rest of the app works fine.
Any help aprecciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to extract the data out of the **DocumentSnapshot**, as in:

```dart
Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context,DocumentSnapshot document){
    var data = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(data['name'])
    );
  }
```

Also I don't see the **name** property in the Firebase document structure, you do have **title** and **description**, though.